# Trying to pass variable values from PHP to a new HTML file

Tags: php, html, forms

using PHP 5.6.27 I'm trying to generate a HTML file by combining

(1) Input from form fields

(2) HTML code (template)

Issue: The file gets created but only has the $template value but not the form field input.

Code is below.  Also Live link is at  http://fastlaw.in/formv2.html

Sure I'm missing something simple, but would appreciate it if anyone can help out.

**formv2.html**

```
<form action="formscriptv2.php" method="POST">

    <input id="field1" type="text"/> <br />
    <input id="field2" type="text" /> <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">

</form>
```

**formscriptv2.php**

```
<?php
    $Field1 = $_POST['field1'];
    $Field2 = $_POST['field2'];

    $onepart = "
<div class='table table-left'>          
    <section>
    <h2 class='table-heading'>";

    $twopart = "</h2>           
    <table class='data'>
            <caption>
                <p>";

    $threepart = "</p>
            </caption>
    ";

$template = $onepart . $Field1 . $twopart . $Field2 . $threepart;

$ret = file_put_contents('tmp/mydata.txt', $template, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);


    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }

    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Missing `name attribute` in `input type`!!

Comment: thanks Saty, I missed this, had put in the id tag instead. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

PHP `$_POST` array are populated via the `name` HTML attribute:

```
<input id="field1" name="field1" type="text"/> <br />
<input id="field2" name="field2" type="text" /> <br />
```

Comment: Thanks Matt...i put in the form code, as you did and it works now...appreciate you taking the time!